# Get DateTime as UTC with Dapper

Tags: c#, .net, orm, utc, dapper

I'm using Dapper to map my entities to SQL Server CE. If I save a `DateTime` with `Kind=Utc`, when I read it back I get a `DateTime` with `Kind=Unspecified`, which leads to all kind of problems.

Example:

```
var f = new Foo { Id = 42, ModificationDate = DateTime.UtcNow };
Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", f.ModificationDate, f.ModificationDate.Kind);
connection.Execute("insert into Foo(Id, ModificationDate) values(@Id, @ModificationDate)", f);
var f2 = connection.Query<Foo>("select * from Foo where Id = @Id", f).Single();
Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", f2.ModificationDate, f2.ModificationDate.Kind);
```

This code gives the following output:

```
20/09/2012 10:04:16 (Utc)
20/09/2012 10:04:16 (Unspecified)
```

I know I should be using a `DateTimeOffset`, but unfortunately SQL CE has no support for this type.

Is there a workaround? Can I tell Dapper to assume that all dates have `DateTimeKind.Utc`? And more generally, what are my options to customize the mapping?

---

EDIT: My current workaround is to patch the dates after Dapper has materialized the result, but it kind of smells...

```
var results = _connection.Query<Foo>(sql, param).Select(PatchDate);

...

static Foo PatchDate(Foo f)
{
    if (f.ModificationDate.Kind == DateTimeKind.Unspecified)
        f.ModificationDate = DateTime.SpecifyKind(f.ModificationDate, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    return f;
}
```

Comment: It's kind of a limitation of the SQL Server in my experience. Assuming it's UTC was what I did.

Comment: @PeterRitchie, it's a limitation of SQL Server Compact Edition (the "full" SQL Server has a datetimeoffset data type). I could easily work around the issue with vanilla ADO.NET, but my question is more specific to Dapper, which apparently doesn't give me much control over how the result is materialized...

Comment: You could probably call `SpecifyKind` in the property setter. Then it would play nice with most (if not all) ORMs.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque Well, it's more like a limitation of ADO.NET and `DbType.DateTime` mappings.  ADO.NET gives you the `Unspecified`.  There's nothing telling SQL Server the column is "UTC", so ADO.NET follows suit.  It would be nice to have `DbType.UtcDateTime`; but alas... (and if we did, would CE support it? :)

Comment: @ThomasLevesque One of the many reasons I avoid relational databases--too many limitations when it comes to OO and applications.

Comment: I can confirm this isn't something we directly support.... frankly, though, most people use `datetime` (not `datetimeoffset`), even on full SQL server, and this isn't a problem most of the time.

Comment: @MarcGravell, you're right, I don't know what made me think my problems were caused by that, but I made more tests and actually they're not... so the question is pointless now

Comment: A similar problem occurs using Dapper with SQLite. Items which are persisted as UTC get materialized with the DateTimeKind unspecified and the value showing local time.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Adding this answer for anyone else who comes looking for a simple fix. This is possible now with the addition of SqlMapper.TypeHandler in Dapper.

Add this class to convert the value from the db to a datetime with the kind specified as UTC.

```
public class DateTimeHandler : SqlMapper.TypeHandler<DateTime>
{
    public override void SetValue(IDbDataParameter parameter, DateTime value)
    {
        parameter.Value = value;
    }

    public override DateTime Parse(object value)
    {
        return DateTime.SpecifyKind((DateTime)value, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    }
}
```

Then in my Global.asax file of my Web API I add the type handler to dapper.

```
SqlMapper.AddTypeHandler(new DateTimeHandler());
```

If you need to ensure you are always inserting dates as UTC, then on the SetValue method you can use:

```
parameter.Value = DateTime.SpecifyKind(value, DateTimeKind.Utc);
```

Comment: This is absolutely the correct answer. The one difference I would make is put the `SqlMapper.AddTypeHandler` initialization code in something that is SQL-specific, such a static constructor of the connection factory. That way you have this handler initialized no matter where you make the connection from, rather than only via a web service that remembers to initialize it.

Comment: Somehow I never saw this answer... Yes, it's obviously the correct way to do it. Thanks!

Comment: Does this work? I thought Dapper didn't let you override the mapping for built in types.

Comment: Seems that SetValue is indeed never called, so I'm also wondering how this could have worked?

Comment: To make this work: first remove default DateTime handler with SqlMapper.RemoveTypeMap(typeof(DateTime)); and then register yout custom handler with SqlMapper.AddTypeHandler(new DateTimeHandler());

Answer (score 28):

Looked into the Dapper code. Unless mine was out of date, for value types like datetime (which is mapped to DbType.DateTime), dapper just does a simple cast from the IDataReader object.

Pseudo : yield return (DateTime)IDataReader.GetValue(0);

That's the specific case for Datetime out of a bunch of generic code and lambdas.

AFAIK, SQL datetime never stores the offset / timezone so the kind will always say "Unspecified" on any datetime you store and fetch.

So, to do it *cleanly*, you could touch dapper internals:

which is a pain as you'd have to touch a big IL generating method (the DataRow Deserializer) and put in an if case for DateTime.

OR

just put a setter on the DateTime props where UTC is an issue (which is kinda against POCO but is relatively sane):

```
class Foo
{
    private DateTime _modificationDate;
    public DateTime ModificationDate
    {
        get { return _modificationDate; }
        set { _modificationDate = DateTime.SpecifyKind(value, DateTimeKind.Utc); }
    }
    //Ifs optional? since it's always going to be a UTC date, and any DB call will return unspecified anyways
}
```

Comment: Yes, I guess I could do it in the setter. Actually my question is a bit pointless now, because I eventually realized that it wasn't really an issue to have the datetime kind as "Unspecified", but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 5):

Just wanted to put my full solution here for seamlessly integrating `DateTimeOffset` / `DateTimeOffset?` fields/properties with a MySQL 5.7 database (which doesn't support `DbType.DateTimeOffset`) - based on @matt-jenkins answer above:

```
public static class DapperExtensions
{
    class DateTimeOffsetTypeHandler : SqlMapper.TypeHandler<DateTimeOffset>
    {
        public override void SetValue(IDbDataParameter parameter, DateTimeOffset value)
        {
            switch (parameter.DbType)
            {
                case DbType.DateTime:
                case DbType.DateTime2:
                case DbType.AnsiString: // Seems to be some MySQL type mapping here
                    parameter.Value = value.UtcDateTime;
                    break;
                case DbType.DateTimeOffset:
                    parameter.Value = value;
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("DateTimeOffset must be assigned to a DbType.DateTime SQL field.");
            }
        }

        public override DateTimeOffset Parse(object value)
        {
            switch (value)
            {
                case DateTime time:
                    return new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.SpecifyKind(time, DateTimeKind.Utc), TimeSpan.Zero);
                case DateTimeOffset dto:
                    return dto;
                default:
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Must be DateTime or DateTimeOffset object to be mapped.");
            }
        }
    }


    private static int DateTimeOffsetMapperInstalled = 0;

    public static void InstallDateTimeOffsetMapper()
    {
        // Assumes SqlMapper.ResetTypeHandlers() is never called.
        if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref DateTimeOffsetMapperInstalled, 1, 0) == 0)
        {
            // First remove the default type map between typeof(DateTimeOffset) => DbType.DateTimeOffset (not valid for MySQL)
            SqlMapper.RemoveTypeMap(typeof(DateTimeOffset));
            SqlMapper.RemoveTypeMap(typeof(DateTimeOffset?));

            // This handles nullable value types automatically e.g. DateTimeOffset?
            SqlMapper.AddTypeHandler(typeof(DateTimeOffset), new DateTimeOffsetTypeHandler());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried your approach, but somehow I'm continuously getting `InvalidOperationException("DateTimeOffset must be assigned to a DbType.DateTime SQL field.");`. I checked `DbType` prop of `IDbDataParameter` and the value was `AnsiString`. Any thoughts?

Comment: Apologies - yes we discovered this also. Add that type to the top switch case and it works. Will update my answer shortly.

Comment: Cool! Could you provide your value of `MySqlDbType`? Because I have `MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType.Decimal`. How comes that it is `decimal` while `DbType` is `System.Data.DbType.AnsiString`? Really strange...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Dapper from source (not nuget), you could tweak the code to always force DateTimeKind of UTC.  A more configurable option might be to create a new attribute for DateTime property values that allow you to specify date time kind as a hint to dapper.  Dapper could look for DateTime properties with this attribute and when found could use it to specify the DateTime kind during ORM mapping. This might be a nice feature for core dapper as you are not the only one with this issue :)