# Have Dapper assign DateTimes as UTC, Date as Local

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime, dapper

There's a lot of stories around how to [have Dapper assign all `DateTimes` coming back from a query as Utc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12510299/get-datetime-as-utc-with-dapper).

However, my database actually uses the `Date` data type when we don't care about the time of an event (say, a 'due date').  Unfortunately, this gets converted to a UTC `DateTime` in C#. This causes some havoc with date picker UIs, which seem to have strange behavior for users across time zones.

Is there a mechanism within Dapper to capture when a `Date` field is being converted to a DateTime and set the `DateTimeKind` differently? Or force specific TypeHandler to be used for certain columns?

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you are trying to do but with a caveat. You can create a custom TypeHandler but as the class that you are going to map in C# will be a `DateTime` dapper already has it's own handling.

On older versions there were no way to replace those (I know by experience, I had to modify dapper as I had a very similar situation) but now you can remove the mapping with `SqlMapper.RemoveTypeMap`, so you can remove the DateTime mapping and use your custom typehandler.

The caveat: all the DateTimes will be handled by your type handler, you must inside then determine if what you're deserializing is a `Date` or a `DateTime` and apply different logic for both, what can be tricky as you receive an `object` that will be already a `DateTime`.